# openERP 7: How to get the Model name and Action of the Current page?

Tags: javascript, odoo, web-frameworks, openerp-7

I don't how to ask this, but assuming the user goes to "Accounting" > "Suppliers" > "Purchase Receipts", now i need to do something only at that very page.  How do i know that i am at that page?  My solution is to get a variable from instance but I'm not getting any luck or am I looking at this the wrong way?

My code:

```
instance.web.ViewManagerAction = instance.web.ViewManagerAction.extend({
    switch_mode: function(view_type, no_store, view_options){

        // for Testing, output to console the results that are similar to this
        console.log( "account.voucher" + "action='action_purchase_receipt'" );

        // some other code

        return  this._super(view_type, no_store, view_options);
    }
});
```

Code from /addons/account_voucher:

```
   <menuitem
            id="menu_action_purchase_receipt"
            icon="STOCK_JUSTIFY_FILL"
            action="action_purchase_receipt"
            parent="account.menu_finance_payables"
            sequence="10"
            />
```

Answer (score -1):

In your method just call self._name to get the model name.